# Add /usr/local/bin to $PATH calling popen from Excel 2016 (OSX)

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am using Excel 2016 on a Mac. Inside a VBA script, I have

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function popen64 Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "popen" (ByVal command As String, ByVal mode As String) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function pclose64 Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "pclose" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function fread64 Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "fread" (ByVal outStr As String, ByVal size As LongPtr, ByVal items As LongPtr, ByVal stream As LongPtr) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function feof64 Lib "libc.dylib" Alias "feof" (ByVal file As LongPtr) As LongPtr

' @internal
Public Type ShellResult
    Output As String
    ExitCode As Long
End Type
Public Function ExecuteInShell(command As String) As ShellResult
    Dim result As LongPtr
    Dim chunk As String
    Dim read As Long

    result = popen64(command, "r")

    If result = 0 Then
        ' TODO Investigate why this could happen and what should be done if it happens
        Exit Function
    End If

    Do While feof64(result) = 0
        chunk = VBA.Space$(50)
        read = fread64(chunk, 1, Len(chunk) - 1, result)
        If read > 0 Then
            chunk = VBA.Left$(chunk, read)
            ExecuteInShell.Output = ExecuteInShell.Output & chunk
        End If
    Loop
cleanup:
    ExecuteInShell.ExitCode = pclose64(result)
End Function
Sub Process_Click()
    Dim result As ShellResult
    result = ExecuteInShell("echo $SHELL & whoami & echo $PATH & pwd")
    Debug.Print (result.Output)
 End Sub
```

When I run Process_Click, I see the following:

```
/bin/bash
/Users/tim/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
tim
```

Note the the order is odd, as if each is running on a separate thread (that's probably a hint I'm doing something wrong!). I would like to run a program (rscript) which is in /usr/local/bin. However if I run `ExecuteInShell("/usr/local/bin/rscript")` I get no output. Strangely also, if I `ExecuteInShell("ls")` I see the right contents, but I get a blank result if I `ExecuteInShell("ls /usr/local/bin")`. Perhaps there is some escaping issue?

TL;DR. I need to either add `/usr/local/bin` to my popen $PATH or call my script using `/usr/local/bin/rscript` but I can't! Any assistance much appreciated.

Comment: Could it be a security issue?

Comment: you may find siome help [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-mso_mac-mso_mac2016/macro-from-excel-for-mac-2011-crashing-in-excel/866066c7-594f-49a0-b4ad-2f0d1bbb2aa3)

Comment: you may also find some help at Github [here](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Web/issues/248)

Comment: The output is out of order because you separated commands with `&`, which tells the shell to run all but the last command in the background. If you just want to run them sequentially, separate them with `;`. If you want to run each command only if the previous one succeeded, separate them with `&&`.